# change dimplejs linemarker style

Tags: javascript, series, dimple.js

I was trying to use dimplejs draw a multi-line chart. But the default line marker looks kinda too "big" for my chart. Is there a way to change the size or the color of the linemarker in dimplejs?

Answer (score 1):

After drawing you can modify the shapes:

```
// dimple's draw method will create the shapes in the svg
chart.draw();

// this will select the markers and set the radius to 2
svg.selectAll(".dimple-marker,.dimple-marker-back").attr("r", 2);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I want. I have another question though, currently, the marker is filled with white. I have assigned each line in my multiple line chart manually with a color. Is there any way to remove that "white" fill, and let the marker has the same color of each line?